# Ember Controllers vs Views

Tags: ember.js

In my app I'm creating a reusable UI component that will let the user request an appointment with 3 possible times. Since this is a reusable UI component, this would be a view (in my understanding).

Where things get tricky is in the implementation. For this we'll be using a couple models (one appointment with many times). As I go down the path of adding times and saving the appointment to the server I keep thinking, managing models is usually a controllers job, not the view.

So what is right?

Do I want to create a controller during the view's initialization and do all model manipulation with that? Or is it okay to create the model in the view and manipulate and save it there?

Ultimately I want to just include the view in the template, and everything else should just work:

```
{{#view App.ScheduleAppointment}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusable UI components should be [Components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/). [THIS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/ember-components-a-deep-dive/) is another awesome resource.

And I think you're right, managing models is a controller's job. Not views, or components given they're just pieces of **UI**. Reusable across contexts in the case of components.

To handle models I think you should send actions to the controller: [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/)

```
this.sendAction('action', param1, param2);
```

I'd look something like this, from templates:

```
{{my-component value1=value1 ....  action="actionFromComponent" }}
```

And in the controller:

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        actionFromComponent: function(param1, param2) {
            .....
        }
    }
})
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Good point. This seems to assume that the model saving will be done in the page's controller, right? This component will be included on various pages/controllers. I'd prefer the controllers to not have to know about it, since it's not directly related to them. Can I create a controller that will somehow be loaded with the component, so that it's all self contained? (I tried doing this and it started looking ugly)

Comment: @JeremyGillick yes, you can declare an explicit controller for your component and pull it as dependency into any other controller by using the `needs` array as documented here: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Comment: The component is it's own controller. I tried using the `needs` property as @herom noted, but I doesn't work and I think it shouldn't. Components are isolated from the context in which they are used, meaning you can use them in several contexts (as long as you fulfil it's interface). If you like you can put the saving logic in the component, or have it in a mixin that you would apply to the controllers that use it (I like this better).